# NSString simple pattern matching

Tags: regex, cocoa, nsstring

Mac OS 10.6, Cocoa project, 10.4 compatibility required.

(Please note: my knowledge of regex is quite slight)

I need to parse  NSStrings, for matching cases where the string contains an embedded tag, where the tag format is:

[xxxx]

Where xxxx are random characters.

e.g. "The quick brown [foxy] fox likes sox".

In the above case, I need to grab the string "foxy". (Or nil if no tag is found.)

Each string will only have one tag, and the tag can appear anywhere within the string, or may not appear at all.

Could someone please help with a way to do that, preferably without having to include another library such as RegexKit.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't really general at all. Did you ever find a way to do it with something similar to regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
NSString *subString = nil;
NSRange range1 = [myString rangeOfString:@"["];
NSRange range2 = [myString rangeOfString:@"]"];
if ((range1.length == 1) && (range2.length == 1) && (range2.location > range1.location)) {
  NSRange range3;
  range3.location = range1.location+1;
  range3.length = (range2.location - range1.location)-1;
  subString = [myString substringWithRange:range3];
}
```

Comment: Thank you chrisbtoo! You are the wind beneath my wings. :-)   Just found one small error though on line 6. should be: "range3.location = range1.location + 1". Big cheers.